# Why does batching with a dataloader not work in a test?

Tags: node.js, apollo, graphql-js, dataloader

## Problem

I am trying to test the performance of the following query:

```
query {
  classes {
    teachers {
      user_id
    }
  }
}
```

When I start up my server and run the query through the graphQL playground, the dataloader works as expected and batches the queries: `teachersForClasses` only runs once.

When I run the test to benchmark the query's performance, `teachersForClasses` runs once for each unique class returned by `getClasses`.

Why do the behaviours differ? In both cases an HTTP request is being sent to an already running server.

## Background

I am using the dataloader library for node.js on a project where I create a graphQL API with Apollo Server.

### Code

```js
function getClasses(args, ctx) {
  /* returns a list of Class objects */
}

const resolvers = {
  Class: {
    teachers: (parent: Class, _args, ctx: Context) => 
      ctx.loaders.class.teachers.load(parent.class_id)
  }
  Query: {
    class: (_parent, args, ctx): Promise<Class[]> => getClasses(args, ctx)
  }
}
```

The loader is defined like this:

```js
function teachersForClasses(classIds: readonly string[]) {
  console.log(classIds) // added for debugging
  /* returns an array of User objects for each class ID */
}

export const loader = {
  class: {
    teachers: new Dataloader<string, User[]>>(teachersForClasses)
  }
}
```

### Tests

A server is already running at http://localhost:8080 before this runs.

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080'
const request = supertest(url)

async function runQuery(token: string) {
  return request
    .post('/user')
    .set({
      ContentType: 'application/json',
      Authorization: token
    })
    .send({
      query: `
      {
        classes {
          teachers {
            user_id
          }
        }
      }`
    })
}

describe('benchmarks', () => {
  it('getTeachersForClasses', () => {
    /*populates the database with data*/

    ...

    for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.time('query')
      const start = Date.now()
      await runQuery(userToken)
      const end = Date.now()
      console.timeEnd('query')
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem: there was an async directive (permission check) for 'teachers' which meant that each time the dataloader was called with `.load()`, it was part of a different event loop 'tick' ([explained here](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader#batching)) & thus the calls weren't batched as expected.

This wasn't an issue in the graphQL playground because I was making the call with an admin user, so the directive resolved immediately.

Comment: What did you do to solve it?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember & I don't have access to this code anymore :/ 
My guess is that I found a way of only doing one permission check per batch?